# MATLAB - hierarchy clustering upon two data sets

Tags: matlab

I have two data sets (characteristic_1, characteristic_2) corresponding to five objects (each). Every object has tree attributes, att1, att2, att3.
So for characteristic_1, the matrix is: 
d= [ 1 1 0; 1.1 1 2; 0.9 0.2 1; 1.2 0.8 1.3; 1 1 1]
and for characteristic_2, the matrix is: 
e= [ 1.1 1 0; 1 1 2; 0.7 0.2 1.1; 1.2 0.8 1.3; 1.3 1 1]

I want to use the hierarchy method (i.e. single linkage), in order to cluster characteristic_1 & 2 (between them). The 5 objects, as well as the 3 attributes, are common in the two characteristics.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is your question? What have you tried? What errors have you obtained?

Comment: My question is how to proceed in general. I have to estimate for each matrix the distance (pdist), the linkage (using i.e. the single method) and find the cophenetic correlation coefficient etc separately (for the two matrices) and then in some way (i don't know how), to conclude something? or i have to create a new matrix (correlating d & e) and then to proceed?

Comment: I don't understand the setup of your problem, but likely is not a specific problem of Matlab, maybe fits better as a general Machine learning problem. If the objects are the same and you want to find clusters among the five objects, then you should use only a matrix with six features, i.e, feat = [d e]. On the contrary, if the features are the same and the objects are different, your goal maybe is to find clusters among the ten objects, the you should use a feature matrix this one: feat=[d; e]